# C++ GTKmm - How do I get the content of my TextView (TextBuffer)

Tags: c++, textview, gtkmm, gtk-textbuffer

I am learning GTKmm (C++) on Linux.

I want to get the content of a TextView via the press of a button.

The code `std::cout << m_textBuffer->get_text();` does not output anything to the console, and I can't find enough explanation on the official website.

It seems that I need to use iterator, but trying to do so with `m_textBuffer->start()` in the function `get_text()` tells me that start() isn't a function of TextBuffer, as well as an end() equivalent.

The console output a few warning which might be related :

> Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark: assertion 'GTK_IS_TEXT_MARK (mark)' failed
>   Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_text_layout_get_line_yrange: assertion '_gtk_text_iter_get_btree (iter) == _gtk_text_buffer_get_btree (layout->buffer)' failed

In the GUI constructor, I have this :

```
m_txtQuestion.set_buffer(m_textBuffer);

m_textBuffer = Gtk::TextBuffer::create();
m_textBuffer->set_text("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(for gtkmm-2.4 and gtkmm-3.0):
Instead of trying to set a buffer, just use the one in the TextView:

```
m_txtQuestion.get_buffer()->set_text("My text.");
```

Then to get the text use:

```
m_txtQuestion.get_buffer()->get_text();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For clarification, m_txtQuestion was the TextView, m_textBuffer was the TextBuffer. So, I don't need to create a TextBuffer as the TextView already provide one (should have read the doc more carefully). I can now output it back to the console, however it will only display the text (whith `std::cout << m_textBuffer->get_text()` ) when the program close, BUT it displays immediately if I does `std::cout << m_textBuffer->get_text() << "\n"` (or if I replace \n with std::endl). If you can tell me why that would be great, but so far it's just curiosity. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I wasn't paying attention to which object was the TextView.  I edited my answer to use the TextView.  I'm not sure why it's not printing until the program closes (you may need to process an event or signal, like on_click, and put the print in the signal handler).

Comment: Note: std::endl flushes the output stream (in addition to inserting a newline), that may be why you see immediate console display when using it.  As for "\n", I'm not sure why that displays immediately, unless the library implementation treats it like std::endl.